# Android Pre-Launch Report touch target size warning for Snackbar

Tags: android, google-play, accessibility

I'm looking at the issues in Android Play Console Pre-Launch Report.

I'm getting a lot of accessibility warnings saying that Snackbar Layout is too small. There are 20+ warnings, some complaining that the height is 1dp, others that it is 47dp. I don't control the size of the snackbar, this is Google code.

Is this a bug in pre-launch reports or am I missing something?